# How & why does the law of vector addition work?

Tags: forces, vectors, geometry, linear-algebra, displacement

Our teacher explained vector addition to us. He explained to us [the triangle law of vector Addition](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn1.byjus.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2019%2F02%2FTriangle-Law-of-Vector-Addition.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fbyjus.com%2Fphysics%2Ftriangle-law-of-vector-addition%2F&docid=0dWHLonNtW5rWM&tbnid=_6VPXgJat5MEMM%3A&vet=1&w=750&h=398&hl=en-US&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim).

I have two questions:

1. He said the vector $\vec{R}$ is the resultant vector, which means that instead of going through $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ we could have directly gone through $\vec{R}$. I don't really understand it and obviously it is easy to understand this intuitively when talking about displacement. But bringing forces and other vector quantities into this image is really hard to understand. So how does the triangle law work for adding forces?
2. The head-tail combining rule is confusing and appears as a trick to enable memorization. So if there is a triangle law of vector addition, then why is there a need for the parallelogram law Of vector addition, when both are talking about adding entities with directions and magnitudes?

Also, how does one understand force vector addition using the parallelogram law (I believe this question will be answered when the first question is answered)?

Edit: I am new here, so I don't know how to add images to the question. Also please don't answer this question mathematically, please answer in a way that vector additions make sense intuitively and become easy to imagine.

Comment: Maybe with force, you can use Newton's second law to relate it to displacement, and that will help you gain a little intuition as to why it is the way it is 
As for the parallelogram rule, if you look at it the right way I think you'll be able to see that it is actually the same as the triangle rule

Also, I think approaching physics with a "I don't want maths" mindset it definitely the wrong way to do things, if you want to get further in the subject, you'll have to get used to maths, and that doesn't happen by avoiding it

Comment: @MC2k true that maths is involved in physics but I was talking about like proving that Parallelogram and triangle law are same or not using mathematical and identities and tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, it is easy to understand when talking about displacement.

[image]

Then you only need to recognise that a displacement vector is the same vector wherever it appears on the plane.

[image]

(this also shows the parallelogram law. This is not different from the triangle law, just a different way of thinking of it).

So, to apply this to forces, and other vector quantities, you only have to recognise that it does not matter where you put the vectors on the diagram. Of course, it only applies to questions where *only* the vector properties of the forces are relevant -- like when you are calculating the net force acting in a particular direction. It does not apply when you need to take moments, and have to describe the force acting at a point.

Comment: So the answer of triangle law and Parallelogram would be same ?

Comment: yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The triangle law of vector addition is the coordinate-free *definition* of vector addition, so one cannot explain why it describes addition because it *is* addition.

Vectors are geometric objects, regardless of what you are describing. If force is a vector, then its coordinate free definition of addition is the same as displacement vectors, or electric field strengths, or any other vector.

The only thing the parallelogram law adds is that it explicitly shows that addition is commutative:

$$\vec A + \vec B = \vec B + \vec A$$