# Two forces act on a body as shown

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, vectors, free-body-diagram

[image: this image is a question about free body diagram and vector motion]

Two forces act on a body as shown on the grid below. Draw a scale diagram to determine the resultant force acting on the body. Use a scale of 1 cm to 1N

Comment: I know you're new here, but this is *not* a forum for "homework-style" questions, particularly ones that are as common as vector addition - see [This other closed question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/537397/how-why-does-the-law-of-vector-addition-work)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How & why does the law of vector addition work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/537397/)

Answer (score 1):

Length of the  arrows proportional to the magnitude of the force, an then draw the force parallelogram or triangle.